# What's the meaning of this sentence 'the conflict started brewing'?

Tags: idioms-in-context

I have a translation assignment, but this sentence is so confusing to me. It talks about the theory of '21 days to form new habits or get rid of old ones.' ❗️Here is the text:
"Dr. Maltz published his theory in a book that went very famous in that era and sold over 30 million copies. And here, the conflict started brewing and it made sense why people were starting to believe his theory."

Comment: What do you mean by "a translation assignment"? The text you've cited here definitely didn't come from a native Anglophone, so there's not much point in trying to *learn* anything from it.

Comment: I'm majoring in English, but it isn't my first language (teachers usually ask us to do this kinds of assignments-to translate the texts into our 1st language).

Answer (score 2):

In this context, "conflict started brewing" means how a difficult situation is arising from this theory and people were fighting to prove the theory right or wrong, basically those who support/believe the theory and those who oppose/do not believe it.

Google definition of "conflict brewing":

> conflict brewing: used for saying that a difficult, dangerous, or violent situation is developing